# Is there a way to auto-flush/fsync stderr in Python?

Tags: python, pygtk

I have a GUI python program and a simple error logging system via

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open("err.log", "w")
```

and it works mostly fine. The one problem I have is that whenever I encounter a run-time error using Windows 7 and Python 2.7.3, the file err.log gets written only after I close the program. Reading related issues I gather I'd need to perform flush() and os.fsync() to sys.stderr after the error, but I don't know how to do that easily.

One way would perhaps be to perform flush/fsync after every possible point in the program where a run-time error is possible, but this is obviously not a good solution. The main reason for using this error logging is debugging, so by definition I can't really know beforehand where I'd need to flush other than at all the possible places where a run-time error is possible. Since there are a lot of such places I'd prefer not to have to try/catch every one of them.

I'm using PyGTK, so there is no main loop visible to me in which I could do the flush/fsync.

Is there any way to tell Python to always perform flush and fsync after an error, or does anyone have other ideas how to solve this (minor) problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with syhpoon: using `logging` for logging. But if you really need your arrangement, look at the third `buffering` argument to `open` to disable it:

> If the buffering argument is given, 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line
>   buffered, and larger numbers specify the buffer size.  The preferred
>   way to open a file is with the builtin open() function.

I tried this and it works. In a Python session:

```
>>> a = open('/tmp/bar', 'w')
>>> a.write('hi\n')
```

And in another term window:

```
$ cat /tmp/bar
$
```

Then I re-ran the experiment with buffering disabled:

```
>>> a = open('/tmp/bar', 'w', 0)
>>> a.write('hi\n')
```

And:

```
$ cat /tmp/var
hi
$
```

So use `logging`, but if not, see if just disabling buffering will give you what you need.

Comment: This works for me as well and I'll mark this as accepted. However, I'm also curious about logging. I tried a simple example, but there were some issues. Not only was the log file written only after closing the program, I couldn't find a way to get run-time errors to be handled by the logger.

Comment: A more common usage pattern would be to let `logging` write to stderr (which is unbuffered) as usual, then inspect that stream as it's generated. That workflow is very well tested.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a [logging modul](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial)e would we a better choice for logs?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote this down, so I'll just verbally express that I don't consider this answer to be of any use to the question, since the problem didn't have anything to do with the flexibility of logging and whatnot.

Comment: Mature and established logging frameworks provide battle tested solutions for a lot of different child errors like the one you described, that's why it was recommended.